# Javascript won't output values from input box

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to user to press submit button so that their name and age is displayed in the input box with `name="output"`?

I have 3 input boxes, one asking for name and the other for age while the other one provides output. I am trying to use the function `output()` to display the last input box.

I am confused about where I am going wrong, do I need a `.value`?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.formdiv{
    align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function output(){
        var name = getElementByName('firstName');
        var Age= getElementByName('age');
        var out = document.write(name+Age);
        document.getElementByName('output') = out;
    }
</script>

<h1><strong><em><center>Payment Details</center></em></strong> </h1>
<div class="formdiv">
<fieldset><center>
<legend> Enter the following Info:</legend>
<br />
<label> Name </label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="John" required="required"></input> 
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Age </label>
<input type="number" name="age" maxlength="2" required="required"></input>
</fieldset>
</center>
</div>
<div>
<center>
        <button onClick="output()">Submit</button><br/>
<label for="output">Output</label>
<br/>
<input type="textbox" name="output"></input>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's `getElementByName()`?

Comment: I want to use the name attribute to capture what the user entered so to get users name the "firstName" is used

Comment: Here's the fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/sa71h00b/ (It is *way* too early for you to be posting on SO. You need to do *a lot* more research first. Take a free JavaScript course. I recommend codecademy.)

Comment: use getElementsByName not getElementByName

Comment: Thanks, just started learning it the last two days and thought I might try a bit of "learning by doing"

Comment: The getElementsByName method works differently in different browsers. In IE & Opera, getElementsByName() method will also return elements that have an id attribute with the specified value. so you should be careful not to use the same string as both a name and an ID.

here the fixed code https://jsfiddle.net/xodbbeov/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

- there is no such thing as `getElementByName` - it is `getElementById`
- changing to the above, you need to add ids to your input elements
- you need to use the `value` of the returned object from `getElementById`
- The above will get your code working, but also, the `center` tag is obsolete and you shouldn't use it
- Inputs are self closing tags so you don't need `</input>`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    .formdiv {
      align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function output() {
      var name = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
      var Age = document.getElementById('age').value;
      var out = name + Age;
      document.getElementById('output').value = out;
    }
  </script>

  <h1><strong><em><center>Payment Details</center></em></strong> </h1>
  <div class="formdiv">
    <fieldset>
      <center>
        <legend>Enter the following Info:</legend>
        <br />
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="John" required="required"></input>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label>Age</label>
        <input type="number" name="age" id="age" maxlength="2" required="required"></input>
    </fieldset>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div>
    <center>
      <button onClick="output()">Submit</button>
      <br/>
      <label for="output">Output</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="textbox" name="output" id="output"></input>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working version of your code.

1. There's no method getElementByName (but [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)) - you should use `document.getElementById()` ([Read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById))
2. You should use the `value` of the input element.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.formdiv{
    align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function output(){
        var name = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
        var Age= document.getElementById('age').value;
        document.getElementById('output').value = name+Age;
    }
</script>

<h1><strong><em><center>Payment Details</center></em></strong> </h1>
<div class="formdiv">
<fieldset><center>
<legend> Enter the following Info:</legend>
<br />
<label> Name </label>
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="John" required="required"></input> 
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Age </label>
<input type="number" id="age" maxlength="2" required="required"></input>
</fieldset>
</center>
</div>
<div>
<center>
        <button onClick="output()">Submit</button><br/>
<label for="output">Output</label>
<br/>
<input type="textbox" id="output"></input>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) (note: `Elements`, not `Element`) returns a list of `Element`s, in this case your `<input>`s. So first of all, you need to select the first (in your case your only one) using `getElementsByName(...)[0]`. Then you get one `Element`.

However you do not want to output the entire element (which is an `Object`, not a `String`, and converted to a string it likely won't be what you expect), so you need to select the value property of that `Element`. So yes, you need to add `.value`, just as you assumed:

```
function output(){
    var name = getElementsByName('firstName')[0].value;
    var Age= getElementsByName('age')[0].value;
```

Then, [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) writes the argument to a new document directly, which results in an emtpy page with nothing else on it but that string. This isn't what you want, so you don't need that. ALl you **do** want is to assign a new variable called `out` with that string:

```
    var out = name+Age;
```

Then to assigning the new value to the output field - you don't want to replace the `Element` by a string (that wouldn't even work), but it's value, so you need the `.value` again:

```
    document.getElementsByName('output')[0].value = out;
}
```

That should do the trick.

(In addition to that, you might want to use `name + " " + Age` instead of simply `name+Age`, as otherwise you end up with "John Doe23" instead of "John Doe 23" which you likely want)